# Change the position and size of Chrome extension window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We want to change the position and height of the chrome extension window when we click the extension icon in the browser.
The extension is not popup window.
We are going to do it using Javascript. Can you give me some codes please on how to do this?

Comment: please provide more details, maybe some pictures to explain your problem. what is your "extension window"?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why if the popup window isn't in use at all, you'd care about its dimensions and location. Why show it?

That being said, height and width can be changed. Simply set them in css for `html` and `body` elements. If by changing position you mean that upon click the popup would open in the center of the screen (for example), as far as I know, this cannot be done. It must point to the extension's icon.